# Trouble declaring unique fields in prisma view

Tags: database, postgresql, orm, prisma

Currently having some trouble adidng some unique fields to prisma. I have some views declared in my schema, however, according to the documentation, each view needs at least one unique identifier, which in my case doesnt happen, due to being a timescale database. I also cant guarantee that any composite constraints will be unique.

Is there any problems if the fields declared within @@unique aren't unique?